# Limiting sharp drop off of coastal DEM raster where there is no data using QGIS?

Tags: dem, qgis-3, nodata

I'm stitching numerous tiled DEM's using **Build Virtual Raster** and then '**Align raster**' function within QGIS 3.6

Original DEM has no data for sea area as expected:
[image]

I get sharp drop off on coastal/harbour locations

[image]

Original single tile header detail in asc:

[image]

Following '**Align**' task within QGIS:

[image]

Is there anything I can do to smooth this transition?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the NoData value to something closer to sea level?

Comment: There is no option to set NoData value within the 'Align Rasters' QGIS feature.
Is there another gdal command that may be able to carry out 'same stitch multiple rasters' procedure whilst adding the custom NoData value. Otherwise I assume I could take the single output raster from 'Align Rasters' and then carry out a gdal_translate and add in the NoData required?